# Joining two collections in a view MongoDB; what does the unwind do?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got the collections `user` and `domain` and I want a view combining them.

```
db.createView( "userDomainRelation", "user", [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "domain",
            localField: "domain",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchDomain"
         }
   },
   {
      $project:
         {
           _id: 1,
           email: 1,
           firstName: 1,
           lastName: 1,
           accountType: 1,
           domain: 1,
           host: "$matchDomain.host",
           isOpenDomain: "$matchDomain.isOpenDomain",
           isPartnerDomain: "$matchDomain.isPartnerDomain"
         }
   }
] )
```

This works, but I want the fields from `domain` not as an array. This is done with `unwind`:

```
db.createView( "userDomainRelation", "user", [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "domain",
            localField: "domain",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchDomain"
         }
   },
   {
      $project:
         {
           _id: 1,
           email: 1,
           firstName: 1,
           lastName: 1,
           accountType: 1,
           domain: 1,
           host: "$matchDomain.host",
           isOpenDomain: "$matchDomain.isOpenDomain",
           isPartnerDomain: "$matchDomain.isPartnerDomain"
         }
   },
   {
        $unwind: "$host"
    }
] )
```

The `host` is always present in `domain` for each `user`. If I unwind also the `isOpenDomain` and the `isPartnerDomain` I only get the records where `isOpenDomain` and `isPartnerDomain` are present in 'domain'. Why is this and how can I work around this? I want all domains even if `isOpenDomain` or `isPartnerDomain` is not present.

```
db.createView( "userDomainRelation", "user", [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "domain",
            localField: "domain",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchDomain"
         }
   },
   {
      $project:
         {
           _id: 1,
           email: 1,
           firstName: 1,
           lastName: 1,
           accountType: 1,
           domain: 1,
           host: "$matchDomain.host",
           isOpenDomain: "$matchDomain.isOpenDomain",
           isPartnerDomain: "$matchDomain.isPartnerDomain"
         }
   },
   {
        $unwind: "$host"
    },
   {
        $unwind: "$isOpenDomain"
    },
   {
        $unwind: "$isPartnerDomain"
    }
] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`$unwind` behaviour](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is to skip empty arrays & null values. So records which would have those fields as missing are not included. Use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` if you want records to always be present. See [this example from the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#missing-or-non-array-values).

**More importantly**, for your useage, you should do the unwind *before* your `$project`, or rather, *just after the `$lookup`* (as appropriate). And by unwinding just the `matchDomain` field, it will include all the fields within it - and doesn't need the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` part.

```js
db.createView( "userDomainRelation", "user", [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "domain",
            localField: "domain",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchDomain"
         }
   },
   {
      $unwind: "$matchDomain"
   },
   {
      $project:
         {
           _id: 1,
           email: 1,
           firstName: 1,
           lastName: 1,
           accountType: 1,
           domain: 1,
           host: "$matchDomain.host",
           isOpenDomain: "$matchDomain.isOpenDomain",
           isPartnerDomain: "$matchDomain.isPartnerDomain"
         }
   }
] )
```

If you provide some test data/examples, then we can see what you're actually trying to get.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. Nice you also included the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays.